# vscode and jsdocs - How to use TS interfaces or types for javascript functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I know that a type or an interface can be used for intellisensing function params or inline `@type`'s. But is there some way to use types/interfaces to give intellisense to whole functions or object literals? Example:

```
type TFunc = ( x: number ) => boolean;

/**
 * @implements {TFunc}
 */
function isNumber ( x ) {
    return typeof x === 'number';
}
```

`@implements` doesn't work. I wonder if that can be done in another way?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible currently, here is the relevant issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30156

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

Use `@type` rather than `@implements`